# How to change the parameter of a Function<T,R>?

Tags: java, function, interface

Is it possible to to change the type of the attributes from the  [Function<T,R> interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) ?

For example I have the class `integerMap` which applies a given `Function<Integer[],Integer>` to an `Integer[]`.
The `intWrapper` method however takes a function with the input type `int[]`.

My aim is to call the integerMap- from the funwrap  method and apply a changed version of its own `Function`with the same instruction, just with 'Integer[]' instead of 'int[]' in order to turn a `Function<int[],Integer>` to `Function<Integer[],Integer>`and use it in integermap.

```
 public static Integer integerMap(Function<Integer[],Integer> integerFun, Integer[] integerArr){
       return integerFun.apply(integerArr);
   }

      Function< Function<int[],Integer> , Function<Integer[],Integer> > funWrap = new Function<Function<int[], Integer>, Function<Integer[], Integer>>() {
          @Override
          public Function<Integer[], Integer> apply(Function<int[], Integer> integerFunction) {
              // Change the input attribute from int[] to Integer[]
          }
      };
```

I tried to make a Function `integerFunction`, which takes two `Function` as Attributes, but I don't understand how to access the `byte[]` of the input Attribute and how to alter it.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see. You have a `Function<Integer[],Integer>` and want to apply it to `int[]`. In other words: you want a `Function<int[],Integer>`. Code duplication is bad, so you'd like one method to act as adapter for the other.

```
Function<Integer[], Integer> fboxed = ints -> Stream.of(ints).reduce(0, Integer::sum); // just a dummy impl
Function<int[], Integer> fprimitive = ints -> fboxed.apply(box(ints));

private static Integer[] box(final int[] ints) {
  return IntStream.of(ints).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
  // or use https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toObject(byte[])
}
```

Put differently: you have two functions A→R, and want a function B→R. This means you need to convert from A to B, i.e. A→B.
Maybe you'd like to go full Function:

```
// A→B
Function<int[], Integer[]> fbox = ints -> IntStream.of(ints).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);

// A→R
Function<int[], Integer> fprimitive = ints -> fboxed.apply(box(ints));
// B→R
Function<Integer[], Integer> fboxed = ints -> Stream.of(ints).reduce(0, Integer::sum); // still a dummy impl
```

Of course, `Function` is simply a SAM type (single abstract method), so everything could be written as regular methods and references to those methods then stored in variables.

```
class Functions {
    public static Integer primitive(final int[] ints) {
        return boxed(box(ints));
    }

    public static Integer boxed(final Integer[] ints) {
        return Stream.of(ints).reduce(0, Integer::sum);
    }

    private static Integer[] box(final int[] ints) {
      return IntStream.of(ints).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
    }

    private static Function<int[], Integer> fint = Functions::primitive;
    private static Function<Integer[], Integer> finteger = Functions::boxed;
}
```

In case the above was not clear enough (it can be confusing!), what you actually want to do, is to have your `Integer[]->Integer` function unwrap its argument and then delegating to your `int[]->Integer` function, acting as an adapter. So the "conversion" is actually inverted (`Integer[]->int[]`).

```
public static Function<Integer[], Integer> funwrap(Function<int[], Integer> intFunction) {
    return integers -> intFunction.apply(unbox(integers));
}

private static int[] unbox(final Integer[] ints) {
    return Stream.of(ints).mapToInt(x -> x).toArray();
}
```

So the transformation `I[]→i[]→I` from indistinquishible from `I[]→I` when viewed from the outside.

- Original: `I[] | I[]→I`
- Adapted: `I[] | I[]→i[] | i[]->I`